# Converting from JUnit 4 to TestNG. How do I deal with a parameter?

Tags: java, testng, junit4

I am trying to convert my already bulging project from JUnit 4 to TestNG, in order to get some decent reports out of it.

I have been following a tutorial at http://test-able.blogspot.co.uk/2016/10/how-to-convert-test-classes-from-junit-to-testng.html

But I do not get this bit at all.

In my existing code, I had the following:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameter;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@Parameter
public static String browserName;  

@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data () { 
    Common.printLine();

    debug.print(thisClass + " set up browser parameters: " + global.variables.browsers);

    switch(global.variables.browsers) {
        case "all":
            Object[][] data = { {"firefox"}, {"chrome"}, {"edge"} };
            return Arrays.asList(data);   
        case "firefox":
            Object[][] data1 = { {"firefox"}};
            return Arrays.asList(data1); 
        case "chrome":
            Object[][] data2 = { {"chrome"}};
            return Arrays.asList(data2); 
        case "edge":
            Object[][] data3 = { {"edge"}}; 
            return Arrays.asList(data3); 
        default:
            Object[][] data4 =  { {"firefox"}};
            return Arrays.asList(data4); 
    }  
}
```

The replacement code for testNG looks fine for the Parameters bit:

```
    @DataProvider(name = "data")
public static Collection<Object[]> data () { 
    Common.printLine();

    debug.print(thisClass + " set up browser parameters: " + global.variables.browsers);

    switch(global.variables.browsers) {
        case "all":
            Object[][] data = { {"firefox"}, {"chrome"}, {"edge"} };
            return Arrays.asList(data);   
        case "firefox":
            Object[][] data1 = { {"firefox"}};
            return Arrays.asList(data1); 
        case "chrome":
            Object[][] data2 = { {"chrome"}};
            return Arrays.asList(data2); 
        case "edge":
            Object[][] data3 = { {"edge"}}; 
            return Arrays.asList(data3); 
        default:
            Object[][] data4 =  { {"firefox"}};
            return Arrays.asList(data4); 
    }  
}
```

This is what is suggested as equivalent for parameter, but I don't understand how to apply it?

```
@Test(dataProvider="data")
public void test2(String keyword) {

}
```

Can anyone explain how to adapt my parameter shown above, browserName?

I think browserName previously held the output from the Collection object, so that when, for instance, the input parameter (global.variables.browsers) was set to 'all', the test would be performed for each of the browsers in order.
(as shown here: http://test-able.blogspot.co.uk/2016/03/do-cross-browser-test-automation-like-a-pro-part2.html)

Comment: It should work. What is your problem?

Comment: What should work '@juherr? The question was, how do I adapt my parameter browserName?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the parameter feature](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters) of TestNG:

```
@Parameters("browserName")
@DataProvider(name = "data")
public static Collection<Object[]> data(String browserName) { 
  // ...
}
```

With suite:

```
<suite name="My suite">
  <parameter name="browserName"  value="all"/>
  <test name="Simple example">
  <-- ... -->
  </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Thanks @Juherr, but I think it is the other way round. The browserName parameter should be output from public static Collection<Object[]> data ()..I want to input 'all' and have it run firefox, chrome and edge one after the other!

Comment: I give up! I accidentally marked the above as the answer, but it isn't. Stupid system will not let me undo it!  Have decided to scrap this approach & try another.

Comment: @SteveStaple - The code snippet provided by Julien does exactly that. It takes the value of `all` from your suite xml file, which gets passed to the data provider named `data` and depending on the value passed to it, you can have the data provider method, return an array of 1D array whose size is 1. this 2D array would contain all your browser flavors and your test would consume the `browserName` per iteration and then run accordingly.

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan - it did not do that when I tried it.Instead, I went for this approach: https://intensetesting.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/how-to-automate-cross-browser-testing-using-testng-2/

Comment: @SteveStaple - Can you please post the original code that you got after applying julien's suggestion ? The link that you shared, basically achieves the same using a round about fashion viz., using multiple `<test>` tags.

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan. browserName is not meant to be the input parameter. In the original version, it held the successive values of the browser being used for the iteration.